# Unique Clustered Index - can I make non-unique without drop/create

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

I have a unique clustered index that is causing replication problems (see "bounded updates").  Is there any way, short of dropping the clustered index, to make the index non-unique?

Answer (score 2):

Is the clustered index also the primary key?  If the clustered index is the primary key, then a unique clustered is also created.  This mean you have to drop and create.

If the clustered index is not the primary key, you can use with drop existing to drop/create the index.

e.g.

```
create clustered index MyIndex on MyTable(MyColumn[s]) with(drop_existing=on);
```

Comment: @adam_haines It is not, but the table's rather large.  The drop existing is worth mentioning in general, though. Thanks.